# SVG: <animateMotion> Using keySplines not working in Firefox

Tags: html, svg, smil

I'm using a custom easing function, so I'm using `keySplines`, `keyTimes` and `values` attributes to achieve this. This animation works in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox the ball object is supposed to follow the loop path, does not move at all (instead ball is in the top left corner, due to not having x y position).

If I remove those attributes then animation plays in Firefox, but without the easing function which is what i want.

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="156.761"
      height="139.855"
      viewBox="0 0 156.761 139.855"
    >
      <circle id="ball" r="5" fill="red"/>
        <path
        id="foo-rail"
        fill="none"
        stroke="lightgrey"
        d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />
      <animateMotion
        href="#ball"
        dur="2s"
        begin="0s"
        fill="freeze"
        rotate="auto"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines="0.31 0.24 0.41 0.88"
        keyTimes="0;1"
        values="0;1"
      >
        <mpath href="#foo-rail" />
      </animateMotion>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Seems like Firefox can't apply keyspline easing on motion paths with more than 1 segment. See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/xxQdQye). I've stripped the 2. curve segment and it works. Probably a bug you should report.

Comment: @herrstrietzel not a bug in Firefox, see my answer. Maybe some other browser has a bug you should report :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the `values` and the `keyPoints` attributes here that is important.

- `values`, same as `from`, `to`, or `by`, according to the [spec](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#AnimateMotionElement) of `<animateMotion>`, *"must consists of a list of x, y coordinate pairs"*. They are meant to provide a path in the form of a polyline (but with subtle differences in the syntax). The `value` attribute should be ignored if a `path` attribute or a `<mpath>` child element is present. For example, you can describe a move from left to right across the viewport as `values="0% 50%; 100% 50%"`.
- `keyPoints` are an extension of SVG to the SMIL format. They use floating point numbers in the 0...1 range to [describe](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#KeyPointsAttribute) how far along a path an object should be moved: *"Distance calculations use the user agent's distance along the path algorithm."* For example, you can describe a forth-and-back movement as `keyPoints="0;1;0"`.

Your code mixed up both. Just rename `values` to `keyPoints`, keeping the value list, and your animation works as expected.

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="156.761"
      height="139.855"
      viewBox="0 0 156.761 139.855"
    >
      <circle id="ball" r="5" fill="red"/>
        <path
        id="foo-rail"
        fill="none"
        stroke="lightgrey"
        d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />
      <animateMotion
        href="#ball"
        dur="2s"
        begin="0s"
        fill="freeze"
        rotate="auto"
        calcMode="spline"
        keySplines="0.31 0.24 0.41 0.88"
        keyTimes="0;1"
        keyPoints="0;1"
      >
        <mpath href="#foo-rail" />
      </animateMotion>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I really need to be more cautious before assuming potential Firefox bugs! Thanks for shedding light on this context.

Comment: Firefox SVG is usually spec compliant to the letter, so if it doesn't work in Firefox, it's probably my code at fault!

Answer (score 1):

Per the [SMIL specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#animateMotionElement)

> When a path is combined with "discrete", "linear" or "spline" calcMode settings, the number of values is defined to be the number of points defined by the path, unless there are "move to" commands within the path.  A "move to" command does not define an additional "segment" for the purposes of timing or interpolation. A "move to" command does not count as an additional point when dividing up the duration, or when associating keyTimes and keySplines values. When a path is combined with a "paced" calcMode setting, all "move to" commands are considered to have 0 length (i.e., they always happen instantaneously), and should not be considered in computing the pacing.

- So you need 4 keyTimes for your path and you've only supplied two.
- Because of the above point, you need 3 keySplines and you've only supplied one.

Your animation is therefore in error and should not run.

It seems like you've found bugs in both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this point! Honestly, I find the buggy implementation more convenient ;)

Comment: @herrstrietzel You **can** use the "buggy" implementation, it just needs the `keyPoints` attribute to work. See my answer.

Comment: thanks to @ccprog, I prefer using `keyPoints` and marked it as solution. But if I were to follow this answer instead, I don't understand what the 4 `keyTimes` and 3 `keySplines` values would look like. Like this `keyTimes="0; 0.25; 0.5; 0.75; 1"` `keySplines="0.31 0.24 0.41 0.88;0.31 0.24 0.41 0.88;0.31 0.24 0.41 0.88"`?

Comment: @CalebTaylor that's 5 keyTimes